# htaccess Rewrite affecting PHP sessions

Tags: php, .htaccess, session, session-cookies

I'm working on a shopping cart using PHP on Apache-server. In short it works like this: PHP session-ID is used as cart-id for a shopping session. After purchase complete, the session-ID is cleaned and a new one is created.

This is working as expected when using this type of URL:

```
www.xyz.com/category.php?catid=11
```

Now something strange happens when I activate SEO-URL's using mod Rewrite

```
www.xyz.com/c/jeans/women
and
RewriteRule ^c/(.*) /category.php?catid=$1 [QSA]
```

Using this method, the actual session_id() switches between 3-4 different session-ID's when I navigating around the website..

First thought was some caching issue or the like, but then I found out this:

```
www.xyz.com/categories/jeans/women
and
RewriteRule ^categories/(.*) /category.php?catid=$1 [QSA]
```

This works as expected! 
When using "categories" instead of "c" as identifier, it works!

What am I missing here? Is my Rewrite-syntax wrong? Why do ^c apparently affect the PHP-sessionhandling, while ^categories do not?

Comment: I wouldn't think .htaccess changes would affect your session, unless it gets passed through queries. How does your `session_id()` handling work?

Comment: Go check what `path` value your session cookie gets set with.

Comment: `the actual session_id() switches between 3-4 different session-IDs` - how are you seeing this? Show us the code.

Comment: path=/
I'm seeing different IDs for every page-refresh, using session_start(); followed by a simple echo session_id(); 

Note; this works 100% when not using mod rewrite. I must be ignoring somethig..

Comment: @04FS Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=qopgqnogs2vfs1mhulirk0g5m4; path=/

Comment: With the path properly set to /, there should be no issues caused by (effectively) changing the URL “path” using rewriting. Can you verify this is the path set for _every_ session cookie? (If you get new session ids, you should get “new” cookies as well. Make sure they all specify the path like this, otherwise you would be dealing with different cookies of the same name under different paths.)